# Traversing Gaps in sequential data

Tags: t-sql

I have a table [ContactCallDetail] which stores call data for each leg of a call from our phone system. The data is stored with a 4 part primary key: ([SessionID], [SessionSeqNum], [NodeID], [ProfileID]). The [NodeID], [ProfileID] , and [SessionID] together make up a call, and the [SessionSeqNum] defines each leg of the call as the caller is transferred from one department/rep to the next.

I need to look at each leg of a call and, if a transfer occured, find the next leg of the call so I can report on where the transfered call went.
The problems I am facing are 1) the session sequence does not always start with the same number 2) there can be gaps in the sequence number 3) The table has 15,000,000 rows and is added to via data import every night, so I need a non cursor based solution.

## Sample data

```
| sessionid    | sessionseqnum | nodeid | profileid |
| 170000459184 | 0             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000459184 | 1             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000459184 | 3             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229594 | 1             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229594 | 2             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229598 | 0             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229598 | 2             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229600 | 0             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229600 | 1             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229600 | 3             | 1      | 1         |
| 170000229600 | 5             | 1      | 1         |
```

I *think* what I need to do is create a lookup table using an identity column or rownum() or the like to get a new sequence number for the call legs that will have no gaps.  How would I do this? Or if there is a different, best practices solution you could point me to that would be great.

Comment: What RDBMS (and version) are you using? Different systems will have different solutions.

Comment: *Why* do you need to eliminate the gaps in the [SessionSeqNum]?  Why can't you just use it as-is?  This is unclear.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - SQL Server Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)
I thought I needed to eliminate the gaps in [SessionSeqNum] because the only way I could figure to get info from the next leg of a transferred call was to do a Left Join that included  A.SessionSeqNum + 1 = B.SessionSeqNum. Obviously this would fail if there were gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lead() analytic function to identify the next session sequence number.

```
SELECT  sessionid ,
        nodeid ,
        profileid ,
        sessionseqnum ,
        lead(sessionseqnum) OVER ( PARTITION BY sessionid, nodeid, profileid ORDER BY sessionseqnum ) AS next_seq_num
FROM    ContactCallDetail
ORDER BY sessionid ,
        nodeid ,
        profileid ,
        sessionseqnum;

sessionid         nodeid  profileid  sessionseqnum next_seq_num
--
170000229594      1       1          1             2
170000229594      1       1          2      
170000229598      1       1          0             2
170000229598      1       1          2      
170000229600      1       1          0             1
170000229600      1       1          1             3
170000229600      1       1          3             5
170000229600      1       1          5      
170000459184      1       1          0             1
170000459184      1       1          1             3
170000459184      1       1          3
```

The ORDER BY clause isn't strictly necessary; it just makes it easier for humans to read the output.

Now you can join the original table to produce a row that shows relevant pairs of rows. There are several different ways to express that in standard SQL. Here, I'm using a common table expression.

```
WITH    next_seq_nums
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        lead(sessionseqnum) OVER ( PARTITION BY sessionid, nodeid, profileid ORDER BY sessionseqnum ) AS next_seq_num
               FROM     ContactCallDetail
             )
    SELECT  t1.sessionid ,
            t1.nodeid ,
            t1.profileid ,
            t1.sessionseqnum ,
            t2.sessionseqnum next_sessionseqnum ,
            t2.nodeid next_nodeid ,
            t2.profileid next_profileid
    FROM    next_seq_nums t1
            LEFT JOIN ContactCallDetail t2 ON t1.sessionid = t2.sessionid
                                              AND t1.nodeid = t2.nodeid
                                              AND t1.profileid = t2.profileid
                                              AND t1.next_seq_num = t2.sessionseqnum
    ORDER BY t1.sessionid ,
            t1.nodeid ,
            t1.profileid ,
            t1.sessionseqnum;
```

The LEFT JOIN will leave NULLs in the rows for the last session sequence numbers in each session. That makes sense--on the last row, there isn't a "next leg of the call". But it's easy enough to exclude those rows if you need to.

---

If your dbms doesn't support the lead() analytic function, you can replace the common table expression above with this one.

```
WITH    next_seq_nums
          AS ( SELECT   t1.* ,
                        ( SELECT    MIN(sessionseqnum)
                          FROM      contactcalldetail
                          WHERE     sessionid = t1.sessionid
                                    AND nodeid = t1.nodeid
                                    AND profileid = t1.profileid
                                    AND sessionseqnum > t1.sessionseqnum
                        ) next_seq_num
               FROM     contactcalldetail t1
             )
             ...
```

Comment: IIRC, `LEAD(..)` is only available in SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: Added a common table expression that doesn't require any analytic functions.

Comment: @mike-sherrill-catcall: The set of columns {sessionid, sessionseqnum} are unique as of now, because we have only one Node and one Profile in our current phone system setup. This could change in the future, and i'm not likely to find out from IT beforehand.

Comment: @Voysinmyhead: If you can have two rows that have the same session id and the same session sequence number, how do you know which one is "next"? (Edit your question and include this information. People who answer need to know.)

Comment: @mike-sherrill-catcall: Two rows can have the same sessionID and sequence number, and be un-related (different calls) IF either the profileID,nodeID or both are different. Where SessionID,NodeID,and ProfileID are the same, the calls are unique and the next greatest existing SessionSequenceNum
-CallA, Leg1: Sessionid=123456 ProfileID=1 Nodeid=1, SessionSequenceNum=1
-CallA, Leg 2: Sessionid=123456 ProfileID=1 Nodeid=1, SessionSequenceNum=2
-CallB, Leg1: Sessionid=123456 ProfileID=1 Nodeid=**2**, SessionSequenceNum=1
-CallB, Leg 2: Sessionid=123456 ProfileID=1 Nodeid=**2**, SessionSequenceNum=2

Comment: @Voysinmyhead: Ah. I see. I expected calls to jump from node to node. Rewrote the code to show the correct joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte 
as 

(SELECT  *, 
rank() OVER 
(partition BY  sessionid,profileid,nodeid
ORDER BY sessionseqnum ) AS Rank
FROM         dbo.Table_1) 


SELECT  
   cte.sessionid,cte.nodeid,cte.profileid,cte.sessionseqnum,cte_1.sessionseqnum
FROM cte LEFT JOIN
cte AS cte_1 
ON cte.sessionid = cte_1.sessionid
and cte.profileid= cte_1.profileid
and cte.nodeid= cte_1.nodeid
and cte.rank= cte_1.rank-1
```